# Open Book Decompositions of M^3's : Finding the Projection Map (Hope in Coordinates) in an Abstract Open Book

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, 3-manifolds

all:
I want to know how to find out , hopefully in coordinates, (but I'll take what's available) , the description of the projection map in an abstract open-book decomposition.

Open book decompositions come in two main types (see below for more):  "actual ones" (just called OBD: Open Book Deomps) and the "abstract ones" (AOBD) . The first is explicitly given, the second consists of a pair (Surface, Self-Diffeomorphism) that gives rise to one, i.e., to an actual AOB.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_book_decomposition

An Open Book Decomposition (OBD) of a 3-manifold $M^3$ is a pair $(B, \pi)$ , where B
is a link, a.k.a., the binding of the OB , which is a submanifold of $M^3$ (a codimension-2 submanifold of $M^3$ ),and $\pi$ is a map so that ($M^3 - B)\rightarrow S^1$ is a fibrarion, i.e., a locally-trivial bundle,in which the fibers are surfaces whose boundary is the binding set B, while the restriction of $\pi$ to B is the angular coordinate; since B is a submanifold of M, it admits a tubular neighborhood $N(B)=B\times D^2$ , where B sits as 
${0}\times D^2$.
   The abstract type is a pair (S,f); S is a compact, oriented surface with non-empty boundary , and f is a self-diffeomorphism that equals Id near $\partial S$, i.e., an element of MCG(S) (mapping-class
 group), and the pair gives rise to an AOB by the construction of a3-manifold $N^3$ defined by:

$N^3:=  N_f \cup (S^1 \times D^2)$

Where $N_f$ is the mapping torus of S by f, and we glue-in  solid tori along each boundary component (remember that $f|_{ \partial S}=Id$ )

And we get an OBD from $N^3$ in which the link/binding B is the core of the solid tori,the the fiber surfaces are the disks along the core. I'm just curious: does anyone know a nice expression for the projection map in an AOB $N^3$?

Thanks.

Comment: I do not quite see what you expect. For a coordinate expression, you need obviously to use local coordinates, and choosing them according to the OBD will give you a trivial expression $(x,y,\theta)\mapsto \theta$. Coordinate-free, what could you possibly want that you did not already explained? Maybe motivation would help understand the question.

Comment: Hmm, good point, let me think it through.

Comment: In fact, the only answer I can think of is to use coordinates $(p,\theta)\in S\times [0,1]$, where $(p,1)\sim (f(p),0)$, and $(p,\theta)\sim (p,\theta')$ whenever $p\in\partial S$.